# Finding an angle in a straight pyramid

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

We have a straight pyramid with a square ABCD as its base and apex S. We're given the pyramid's height 8 and the angle 48 deg. between SA and SC. I've already managed to calculate the pyramid's volume (67.66 cubic meters). and now I'm asked to find the angle between the height SO (O=center of the square base = intersection point of its diagonals) and the pyramid's face SBC. I tried the triangle SOE , E=midpoint of BC, but I can't explain why this works: I know I must draw a perpendicular to plane SBC from some point on SO, yet OE definitely isn't this perpendicular. All I need is to show such perpendicular MUST intersect the line SE at some point is it possible to express the pyramid´s volume with the wanted angle? [image]

Comment: Rats! This high-school stupid problem won't let me now go to sleep...!